# Internet connectivity detection

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection

Both Windows and Android have a way of showing the user that they have lost the internet connection (a yellow triangle icon for Windows and a grey wifi icon for Android). What kind of check do they perform in order to determine whether there is internet connectivity?

I know that bad local network settings can trigger that, but I am asking for cases which are independent of the computer configuration, for example when the router drops WAN connection while the local settings are all correct.

Will these devices check the WAN side of the router or something else?

If the answer is yes, can the setup below trick Windows or Android into thinking there is an internet connection where there is none?

```
Router(1)(LAN) <-------------> (WAN)Router(2) (LAN) <-----------> PC or Android
```

Note that Router(2) is connected via WAN port to Router(1).

Comment: I can't say for sure for Android, but windows checks a file on a server it owns and a DNS resolution (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766017(v=ws.10).aspx). I know Android checks http://www.google.com/generate_204 to determine if there is a captive portal, unsure if its also used to detect internet connectivity.

Comment: so the set-up above won't trick windows?

Comment: No, it won't trick Windows.